# Group by two columns and count and then compare

Tags: excel

I have data in Excel that looks like this:

```
ID  DATE        COST    TOTAL
1   01-01-18    50      100
1   01-01-18    25      100
1   01-01-18    25      100
2   01-03-18    25      100
2   01-03-18    25      100
2   01-03-18    50      100
1   02-01-18    100     100
```

I want to group by ID and Date then count the cost and ensure it quals to the total for that ID and date. So for example ID 1 and date 01-01-18 I want to count the 50 and 25 and 25 and compare it to 100 to return a true or false.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

`SUMIFS` will do what you want. Assuming your example data starts at A1, add a 5th column with this formula in cell E2:

```
=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$7,$A$2:$A$7,A2,$B$2:$B$7,B2)=D2
```

Then fill it down to cell E7.

Comment: Changed to sumifs

Comment: Sorry i should have added that the date needs to be unique aswell. So ID 1 can appear for muliple dates